# Send Email To All Users With Posts In A Project Discussion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having bit of a trouble trying to figure out how I would send an email to all Users that have made a post in a discussion Topic. I have the user_mailer setup and UserMailer.new_post(@post).deliver in the right spot in the controller. Just trying to figure out how to extract just the emails (array of) of Users that have Posts that belong to that Topic.

- User has_many Posts
- Topic has_many Posts
- Posts belongs_to User and also belongs_to Topic

My pseudo code would be:

```
User.emails.where(User.posts == project.post)
```

or something of that sort.

It's almost like; let's say I have a blog. And 10 users comment. I want to be able to trigger my ActionMailer to send an email out to all 10 users if anyone makes a new comment after them.

Would I just put them all under the :bcc for one email or send them as separate emails? So far, I would think to add them under :bcc as an array like [array].join(", ") - is this incorrect?

btw: I am using Heroku, Rails 3.1, and SendGrid addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, after_add: :notify_on_new_post

  def notify_on_new_post(post)
    users_to_notify = posts.map(&:user).uniq - [post.user]
    bcc = users_to_notify.map(&:email).compact * ', '
    # ...
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to scope the users first, and then select the email attribute.

Get users like this:

```
users = User.where(:posts => project.post)
```

and then you can do whatever you want with that array of users, like map the email addresses to an array:

```
user_emails = users.map { |u| u.email }
```